# How to compare percent file size in an if

Tags: bash, arithmetic-expressions

Im trying to do this in a bash shell. Basically want to compare the size of two files by there percentage. If file1 is 90% different then file2 do something:

This is what I have so far:

```
newsize=$(wc -c <"$newfile")
oldsize=$(wc -c <"$oldfile")

if [[ $(($oldsize * 0.9)) -ge $newsize ]]; then
  echo 'This file is 90% or greater'
else
  echo 'This file is not large enough'
fi
```

Im getting an invalid arithmetic operator error on token "0.9"
Any help or pointer would be appropriated

Comment: `bash` can't do floating point maths on its own, only integer maths. Either convert to integer maths as Will suggests, or deploy `bc`, `awk` or some other tool to help out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using integer math (such as `9/10`) instead of floating point.

### Updated Script

```
newsize=525
oldsize=584

if [[ $(($oldsize * 9/10)) -ge $newsize ]]; then
  echo 'This file is 90% or greater'
else
  echo 'This file is not large enough'
fi
```

### Example Output

```
This file is 90% or greater
```